# Maven Spring lombok @AllArgsConstructor is not working

Tags: java, spring

I'm following a tutorial on youtube but I can get a lombok to work specifically AllArgsConstructor. This is a maven project.

I have this pojo;

```
    package com.example.producer;

    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Reservation {
        private String id;
        private String name;
    }
```

And i have this tests:

```
    package com.example.producer;

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.Assert;

    public class ReservationPojoTest {
        @Test
        public void create() throws Exception {
            Reservation re = new Reservation("1", "Jane");
            Assert.assertEquals(re.getName(), "Jane");
        }
    }
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>producer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.12</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

When running my tests in visual studio code it shows me this error:

*The constructor Reservation(String, String) is undefined*

Here is the whole project;
https://github.com/civilian/java-spring-learning

Comment: Did you add the plugin to your IDE as explained in the documentation? https://projectlombok.org/setup/vscode

Comment: The test will probably only pass with the command line maven. You will need a plugin for VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a plugin to make Visual Studio Code understand Lombok annotations. Everything is explained here: https://projectlombok.org/setup/vscode

> Add the [vscode-lombok plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok) to your Visual Studio Code IDE to add lombok support.
>
> - press `Ctrl + Shift + X` to open the extension manager.
> - Type `lombok` to find the plugin, and click `install`.
> - Reload VS Code when asked.